# udev rule for hibernate on low battery not working

Tags: arch-linux, udev

I've been trying to setup an udev rule for hibernating my laptop on low battery. Following the [guide available in the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop#Hibernate_on_low_battery_level) I ended up with the following rule to test if it is working ok:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-lowbat.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{status}=="Discharging", ATTR{capacity}=="[0-99]", RUN+="touch /tmp/test_shutdown"
```

The rule is not being triggered at all as the `/tmp/test_shutdown` is not being created

udevadm monitor output

```
$ udevadm monitor --property
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[6099.285997] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:1b/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
ACTION=change
DEVPATH=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:1b/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
SUBSYSTEM=power_supply
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-poly
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=40
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=15360000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=15855000
POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=9877000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=80400000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=73880000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=51890000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=70
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Low
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=01AY969
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=Celxpert
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=  675
SEQNUM=8036

UDEV  [6099.315142] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:1b/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
ACTION=change
DEVPATH=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:1b/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
SUBSYSTEM=power_supply
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-poly
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=40
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=15360000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=15855000
POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=9877000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=80400000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=73880000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=51890000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=70
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Low
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=01AY969
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=Celxpert
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=  675
SEQNUM=8036
USEC_INITIALIZED=6099287730
```

udevadm test output:

```
$ udevadm test /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

Load module index
Parsed configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/01-md-raid-creating.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/10-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/11-dm-lvm.rules
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/11-dm-lvm.rules:40 Invalid value for OPTIONS key, ignoring: 'event_timeout=180'
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/11-dm-lvm.rules:40 The line takes no effect, ignoring.
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/13-dm-disk.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/49-stlinkv1.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/49-stlinkv2-1.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/49-stlinkv2.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/49-stlinkv3.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-block.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-input-id.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-rfkill.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-sensor.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/63-md-raid-arrays.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/64-md-raid-assembly.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/65-kvm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/65-libwacom.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-dm-lvm-metad.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-md-clustered-confirm-device.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-yubikey.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-infrared.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-joystick.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-mouse.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-touchpad.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-docker.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-libinput-device-groups.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/85-tlp.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/89-alsa-ucm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-backlight.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-libinput-fuzz-override.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-vconsole.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/95-dm-notify.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/96-e2scrub.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-bumblebee-nvidia-dev.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-fuse.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-jlink.rules
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-jlink.rules:356 Unknown group 'dialout', ignoring
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-jlink.rules:357 Unknown group 'dialout', ignoring
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-jlink.rules:358 Unknown group 'dialout', ignoring
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-lowbat.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
DEVPATH=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:1b/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-poly
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=40
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=15360000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=15684000
POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=10476000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=80400000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=73880000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=48080000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=65
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Low
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=01AY969
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=Celxpert
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=  675
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=power_supply
USEC_INITIALIZED=7641133895
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

Your match for capacity is not firing above 9%
You are matching the string against any character between 0 and 9 (inclusive) or character 9. You need to specify compare string as `"[1-9][0-9]"` to match anything between 10 and 99. If You additionaly want to match below 10 you can include another rule specifying `"[0-9]"` here. Alternatively You can check the threshold from within a `PROGRAN` script or directly in Your RUN script where You can use numeric comparison or regular expressions as well as more complex decision trees.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that is not the problem. The original rule was only `"[0-5]"` to trigger when battery is below 5% but it was never triggered. The `"[0-99]"` was just for testing. Anyways, I'll try it and come back

Comment: @Mr.E maybe yes there is anpther problem. But for You testing it cannot work with `"[0-99]"` if You expect it to trigger above 9. So this is at least part of the problem You are describing.

Comment: Also Your system might theroretically have been shut down already before reaching 5. And You should qulify path to touch. (Or even better use a script that logs when it triggers and remove some filters, for beginning maybe everything besides SUBSYSTEM - then check the variables the script got in the scripts log, add the other filters, ...).